[ffmpeg]How to use libfdk_aac to encode pcm to constant bitrate
I have tried both libfdk_aac and aac, but the encoded PCM audio always has a variable bit rate. Why is this happening? How can I make it encode with a constant bit rate
The code is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>   
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AVCodecContext* codec_context = NULL;
    const AVCodec* codec = NULL;
    AVFrame* frame = NULL;
    AVPacket* pkt = NULL;
    FILE* input_file = NULL;
    FILE* output_file = NULL;
    int ret;

    // Open input file
    const char* input_filename = "D:\\audio\\b.pcm";
    const char* output_filename = "D:\\audio\\input.aac";
    input_file = fopen(input_filename, "rb");
    output_file = fopen(output_filename, "wb");
    if (!input_file || !output_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input or output file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Find the AAC encoder
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libfdk_aac");
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codec_context) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set codec parameters
    codec_context->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
    codec_context->sample_rate = 44100;
    codec_context->bit_rate = 256000;
    codec_context->rc_buffer_size = codec_context->bit_rate; 
    codec_context->rc_min_rate = codec_context->bit_rate;   
    codec_context->rc_max_rate = codec_context->bit_rate;  
    av_channel_layout_default(&codec_context->ch_layout, 2);
    // Open codec
    if (avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, &opts) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize packet
    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize frame
    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->nb_samples = codec_context->frame_size;
    frame->format = codec_context->sample_fmt;
    frame->ch_layout.nb_channels = 2;

    // Allocate the data buffers
    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio data buffers\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Main loop: read from the input file, encode, write to the output file
    while (fread(frame->data[0], 1, frame->linesize[0], input_file) == frame->linesize[0]) {
        // Send the frame to the encoder
        if (avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, frame) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending frame to codec\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Get the encoded packet
        while (avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, pkt) == 0) {
            fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, output_file);
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
        }
    }

    // Flush the encoder
    avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, NULL);
    while (avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, pkt) == 0) {
        fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, output_file);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }

    // Clean up
    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_context);

    return 0;
}


I encoded the AAC and then used FFmpeg to write it to an MP4 file: ./ffmpeg -i input.aac -c copy output.mp4, and I checked it using MediaInfo
The PCM file is S16, 2 channels, 44100 Hz
I try to write mp4 directly and check the aac audio through mediainfo which is also a variable bitrate
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>   
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AVCodecContext* codec_context = NULL;
    const AVCodec* codec = NULL;
    AVFormatContext* format_context = NULL;
    AVStream* audio_stream = NULL;
    AVFrame* frame = NULL;
    AVPacket* pkt = NULL;
    FILE* input_file = NULL;
    int ret;
    int64_t next_pts = 0;

    // Open input file
    const char* input_filename = "D:\\audio\\b.pcm";
    const char* output_filename = "D:\\audio\\input.mp4";
    input_file = fopen(input_filename, "rb");
    if (!input_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Find the AAC encoder
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libfdk_aac");
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Allocate AVFormatContext for MP4 output
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&format_context, NULL, NULL, output_filename);
    if (!format_context) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate output context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Add audio stream to the output file
    audio_stream = avformat_new_stream(format_context, codec);
    if (!audio_stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codec_context) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    audio_stream->codecpar->frame_size = codec_context->frame_size = 1024;

    // Set codec parameters
    codec_context->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
    codec_context->sample_rate = 44100;
    codec_context->bit_rate = 256000;
    codec_context->rc_buffer_size = codec_context->bit_rate;
    codec_context->rc_min_rate = codec_context->bit_rate;
    codec_context->rc_max_rate = codec_context->bit_rate;
    av_channel_layout_default(&codec_context->ch_layout, 2);

    // Copy settings to stream
    ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(audio_stream->codecpar, codec_context);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters to stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open codec
    if (avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open output file
    if (!(format_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&format_context->pb, output_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'\n", output_filename);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Write file header
    ret = avformat_write_header(format_context, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize packet and frame
    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->nb_samples = codec_context->frame_size;
    frame->format = codec_context->sample_fmt;
    frame->ch_layout = codec_context->ch_layout;

    // Allocate the data buffers
    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate audio data buffers\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Main loop: read from the input file, encode, write to the output file
    while (fread(frame->data[0], 1, frame->linesize[0], input_file) == frame->linesize[0]) {
        frame->pts = next_pts;  // Set PTS for the frame
        next_pts += frame->nb_samples;  // Increment the next PTS
        // Send the frame to the encoder
        if (avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, frame) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending frame to codec\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Get the encoded packet
        while (avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, pkt) == 0) {
            pkt->pts = pkt->dts = frame->pts;
            av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec_context->time_base, audio_stream->time_base);
            pkt->stream_index = audio_stream->index;
            av_interleaved_write_frame(format_context, pkt);
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
        }
    }

    // Flush the encoder
    avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, NULL);
    while (avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, pkt) == 0) {
        pkt->pts = pkt->dts = next_pts;
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec_context->time_base, audio_stream->time_base);
        pkt->stream_index = audio_stream->index;
        av_interleaved_write_frame(format_context, pkt);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
        next_pts += pkt->duration;
    }

    // Write file trailer
    av_write_trailer(format_context);

    // Clean up
    fclose(input_file);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_context);
    avio_closep(&format_context->pb);
    avformat_free_context(format_context);

    return 0;
}


there is pcm file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Udrtpljmu_7p6bFd2TxYr04iFGeZ6UTE/view?usp=sharing

use command is cbr：.\ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -i input.pcm -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 256k output.mp4
but code is vbr ,why...

This is an issue with Mediainfo and how it identifies bitrate mode.
If you mux to MP4 container instead, using FDK encoder with the same parameters, the resulting output will be shown as Constant bitrate in Mediainfo.

i used command mux to mp4:./ffmpeg -i input.aac -c copy output.mp4
He didn't Re-encode. What's wrong with it?

Mux to MP4 directly inside your code. Don't use the CLI tool to remux to MP4.

Tried it, checked mediainfo and still got a variable code rate.

